# Stop two threads when the condition is meet

Tags: java, android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I want do the following: 2 thread execute the same `Runnable` object. They will generate a random number. Write the number into the log. If the number dividable by 7, stop both thread and a broadcast is sent and the broadcast receiver place the final number on the log with a new tag. I tried both `interrupt()` and volatile but for some reason, one of the two thread will run an extra loop before stop.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Progress dialog",
            "Working....", true);
    Thread one = new Thread(background, "first");
    one.start();

        Thread two = new Thread(background, "second");
        two.start();

    return true;
}//

    Runnable background = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

                while (num1 % 7 != 0 && num % 7 != 0) {

                        try {
                            // just doing some long operation
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            Random rand = new Random();
                            num = rand.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
                            name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                            tag = "before";
                            Log.e(tag, name + ":" + num);
                            if (num % 7 == 0) {
                                num1 = num;
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        } finally {
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                            progDailog.dismiss();
                        }
                } ;
                Intent myObserverSender = new Intent(
                        "action.GO");
                msg = name + ":" + num;
                myObserverSender.putExtra("serviceData", msg);
            sendBroadcast(myObserverSender);
        }

    };

public class MyMainLocalReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context localContext, Intent callerIntent) {
        String serviceData = callerIntent.getStringExtra("serviceData");
        tag = "after";
        Log.e (tag, serviceData);
    }
}
```

Here is final result

```
before: first:7877

before: second:9165

before: first:6760

before: second:5663

After: second:5663 <<<< should stop here

before: first:8025 >>>> this's the extra loop

After: first:5663 >>> wrong
```

By the way, did I do the broadcast correct?

Comment: Is this complete code? I can't see any code to "terminate the thread".

Comment: and...are you putting a ';' at the ending '}' of while...?

Comment: Totally expected. You "sync" both thread "once in the while" (pun intended) that is you check num1 to be divisible by 7. So if both of them are somewhere inside the while, both will end their cycle. If you do not want the "later" thread to potentially overwrite a result from "earlier" Thread, you'd have to check again before setting num1 ...

Comment: By the way ... you are creating a new `Random` object in each iteration and thread - do not do that.

Comment: please show us how you declared num1 and num

Comment: when sleep throws InterruptedException it clears the interrupt flag. since you don't set the flag again in the catch block and you keep on looping, interruption doesn't work. you need to check the interrupted flag in the loop condition or otherwise break out of the loop when you detect an interruption. so if interruption didn't work it may be because you didn't do it right.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simplified version of stopping the threads. This is how it works:

1. The main thread creates a command that stops the other threads.
2. The main threads stores the references to the threads to be stopped
3. The main thread gives the stopper command to the threads so they can call it when needed
4. The stopper command uses an AtomicBoolean to make sure it stops the problematic threads only once.
5. I piggy-backed the thread stopping logic on the `interrupt()` method.

So, here is the full code:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Thread> threads = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        final AtomicBoolean stopping = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        Runnable stopCommand = () -> {
            if (!stopping.getAndSet(true)) {
                for (Thread thread : threads) {
                        thread.interrupt();
                }
            }
        };
        Background background = new Background(stopCommand);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(background);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(background);
        threads.add(t1);
        threads.add(t2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

    private static class Background implements Runnable {

        private Runnable stopCommand;

        public Background(Runnable stopCommand) {
            this.stopCommand = stopCommand;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                int num = rand.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
                System.out.println(name + ", num: " + num);
                if ((num % 7) == 0) {
                    stopCommand.run();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(name + " interrupted. Stopping.");
        }

    }

}
```

Instead of using a list yourself, you can also use executors:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Runnable stopCommand = () -> {
            System.out.println("stopping");
            ex.shutdownNow();
        };
        Background background = new Background(stopCommand);
        ex.submit(background);
        ex.submit(background);
    }

    private static class Background implements Runnable {

        private Runnable stopCommand;

        public Background(Runnable stopCommand) {
            this.stopCommand = stopCommand;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                int num = rand.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
                System.out.println(name + ", num: " + num);
                if ((num % 7) == 0) {
                    stopCommand.run();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(name + " interrupted. Stopping.");
        }

    }

}
```